How to know what details Ubuntu is using for SSH host?
On Ubuntu 23.10, when I open a terminal and ssh in to a host I have like this:
ssh hostname.here.com
It logs me in straight away (even when I've first booted up my machine, not just after I've logged in for the frist time in a session). I have no details for the host in my ~/.ssh/config file either.
Now I need to work out what the username/password (and maybe the key file name) is for that host. I have a record but it's a bit confused (and so far no username/password combination works - but that's another matter).
I have looked at Seahorse, but it doesn't seem to list anything obvious for the host.
How do I find out at least what username and/or key file Ubuntu is using to log in to it? Is there something else Ubuntu uses for remembering terminal logins?


How do I find out at least what username and/or key file Ubuntu is using to log in to it? Is there something else Ubuntu uses for remembering terminal logins?

Use the -v optipn (1,2,3,4, or 5 times for more and more details):
ssh -vvvvv hostname.here.com

will show almost every detail about the connection. Including username, encryption used (and where it found the user; and at that location you shpuld also find the password)
Username can come from .ssh/config but can be overwritten by setting
SSH_DEFAULT_USER (often used in .bashrc.
Username will be shown somewhere at the beginning in the form of
debug1: Authenticating to {host} as {user}

(-v will show the user too)
If you do not provide a user it likely is using your current user. Otherwise it should error out. And in that case it also will ask you for the password.

Yes! That gave me the clues I needed! Thanks!

Are you sure there are authentication methods that involve retrieving the actual password from somewhere? I was looking them up to learn something more about this stuff but none of the methods listed here seem to be involving fetching an actual password: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ssh-authentication-methods

@kos what do you mean? Maybe I wrote it badly (I tend to refer to the (public/private)key as password :P ), Normally the --key-- is found in ".ssh/".  The user can be an ENV var. If a key is not found a password prompt is shown.

Yes you wrote it badly then :D I thought you were referring to a password, not to a key, that's why I was scratching my head. I think OP in the end is just using a public key, possibly stored in ~/.ssh, or retrieved in some other way (or Kerberos, whatever, it appears as thought someone set up the machine for them)

I failed to read this sentence in your question:

even when I've first booted up my machine, not just after I've logged in for the frist time in a session

So if that's the case, this answer won't help, as it assumes at least "something" has been done on the client, at some point; however, I'll leave this answer in for those stumbling upon the same issue when using public-key authentication.

Most likely you're logging in using public-key authentication.
Assuming the public-key authentication has been setup using ssh-copy-id (this is not the only way it could've been done), on the remote host, look at the contents of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; there should be at least one entry that looks like so:
ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxxx user@hostname

where user@hostname is your local username / hostname (rsa may be something else).
Since you're connecting without specifying a username, unless something in ~/.ssh/config is overriding this, the session's username will default to your local user's username; hence you're probably logging in to the server using your local user's username (to find out for sure, you could list the remote user's username on the remote host by running whoami while logged in to the remote host).
As for the remote user's password on the remote host, it's not stored in cleartext anywhere (hopefully), and you can only attempt to guess it, but if the purpose to recover it is to just keep track of it / log in to the server from other machines without setting up public-key authentication for those machines, you may as well just change it to whatever you want:
passwd

At this point you should have everything figured out, and you should be able to log in to the server from other machines using:
ssh user@hostname.here.com

replacing user with your remote user's username and by typing in the new password.

Ah, the contents  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys are a bit of problem as this is a terminal server for a VM host. I can't get to a shell, only start a serial console :-( I thought the user name was "root" and the password for the console was the same as the guest's root password (I can su to root on the guest with that). But perhaps not. I thought something at the client side might give me a clue. I think it must be the name of the user I'm in on the client terminal. So now it's a password problem?

Oh now I've found the password. And it's a password auth using the username on the client machine, not public-key (which was also confusing me!). Thanks for your help though!

@TommyPeanuts Mind to fill me in? Where was the password stored?

Sorry, it was a stupid mistake I'd made in my records (too complicated to explain). Seahorse didn't have it though - not sure why, maybe it only does public key?

@TommyPeanuts No Seahorse doesn't store SSH passwords, my bad, it just manages SSH keys, I believe in the same way you could manually do from the command line with ssh-keygen / fiddling with private / public keys in ~/.ssh

Still, I'm mildly curious how Gnome terminal stores an ssh password against a given username. I don't recall giving the password to a password manager, but maybe I did?

@TommyPeanuts That's why I asked you to fill me in, cause I'm curious, I'm not aware of something that may store the password for a simple ssh command run from the terminal. That's why I also kinda confidently guessed public-key authentication. But if you're sure the correct password is printed using Rinzwind's command, it must be somewhere, doesn't ssh -vvvvv hostname.here.com give a clue?

@TommyPeanuts Ah but you said you recovered the password from your record, so if Seahorse doesn't list the key / you don't have private / public keys in ~/.ssh, you're using a different authentication method. But I can't think of any that doesn't require setting up something on the client. Did this VM get deployed for you pre-configured? In any case ssh -vvvvv hostname.here.com should list all the attempted (and the successful) authentication methods.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
